# LINQ Query .ToList() Fails at runtime

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to understand why the query below fails with

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
            var query = from p in  UserProfiles.ToList()
                    where p.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(lettersToMatch.ToLower()) || p.LastName.ToLower().Contains(lettersToMatch.ToLower()) 
                    select new MembershipSummaryDTO
                    {
                        EmailAddress = p.EmailAddress,
                        FullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", p.FirstName, p.LastName),
                        UserName = p.UserName,
                        IsApproved = p.IsEnabled,
                        UserId = p.UserId
                    };
```

The stack trace points to the WHERE clause

> Line 133: where p.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(lettersToMatch.ToLower()) || p.LastName.ToLower().Contains(lettersToMatch.ToLower())

The fix is to remove the .ToList() on the UserProfiles.ToList() , I would like to understand why this fails (without the fix in place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things before the `.` is `null`. Find out which.

The `ToList` causes most of the query to run as LINQ to Objects which has exactly C# semantics. Without `ToList` most runs in the database which has different semantics for `NULL` values.

Probably, you should *both* understand what is null *and* run the query in the database.

Comment: A null value on the UserProfile.LastName field was the issue. I should have looked at the data being returned before asking away. Thank you for the guidance.